# list of available Windows HotFix IDs per Version

Tags: windows, windows-update, hotfix

I'm working on a utility which extracts the installed HotFix IDs and compares them with the available HotFix IDs

I'm executing the following wmi command to get the list of HotFix IDs

```
wmic /output:\temp\hotfixes.txt qfe list
```

adding a simple process script, then extracting the HotFix IDs like so:

```
["KB2894856", "KB2919355", "KB2894852", ...]
```

### List of Windows HotFix IDs?

Is there a [ list / data source / xml file / json file / ... ] of **windows available Hot Fix ids?**

**What i'm imaging for example:**

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Windows 8.1",
        "version": "NT 6.3",
        "hotfixes": ["KB2894856", "KB2919355", "KB2894852", ...]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Windows 8",
        "version": "NT 6.2",
        "hotfixes": ["KB2894123", "KB2919234", ...]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Windows 7",
        "version": "NT 6.1",
        "hotfixes": ["KB234123", "KB345567", ...]
    },
    ...
]
```

that will give the the reference to compare to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Official Way

http://mybulletins.technet.microsoft.com/BulletinPages/Dashboard

This page generates `.xlsx` document

[image]

[image]

---

## The Naive way

Install each operating system as a virtual machine ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx))

> - Windows 10
> - Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Windows 8
> - Windows Server 2012
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows Server 2008
> - Windows Vista
> - Windows Server 2003 R2
> - Windows Server 2003
> - Windows XP 64-Bit Edition
> - Windows XP
> - Windows 2000

For each one configure to download & install automatic updates (make sure that they're linked to the internet)

Execute on demand the following and extract the list of `KB<id>` for reference to compare with

```
wmic /output:\temp\hotfixes.txt qfe list
```

#### The Result,

Store the results in a `json` file, structured like this

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Windows 8.1",
        "version": "NT 6.3",
        "hotfixes": ["KB2894856", "KB2919355", "KB2894852", ...]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Windows 8",
        "version": "NT 6.2",
        "hotfixes": ["KB2894123", "KB2919234", ...]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Windows 7",
        "version": "NT 6.1",
        "hotfixes": ["KB234123", "KB345567", ...]
    },
    ...
]
```